# How to create custom object in QML?

Tags: qml, qt5

I'm trying to create a custom object in QML, however no success. Am I missing something minor but crucial?

here's the code

some.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Rectangle {
    id: devicesList
    width: 100
    height: 62
    color: "red"

   ListElement {}
}
```

ListElement.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.0


Rectangle {
    id: aaa
    x: 100
    y: 100
    //x: ListElementRoot.xx
   // y: ListElementRoot.yy
    width: 100
    height: 100
    radius: 10
    color: "blue"

    MouseArea {
        id: mouseArea
        anchors.fill: parent
        hoverEnabled: true
        onEntered:{
            animation.start()
            animation2.start()
            animation3.start()
        }
        //onClicked: aaa.width -= 10
        //onEntered:
    }

    PropertyAnimation {
        id: animation
        target: aaa
        properties: "height"
        to: "200"
        duration: 1000
    }

    PropertyAnimation {
        id: animation2
        target: {
            rotation
        }
        properties: "angle"
        to: "72"
        duration: 1000
    }

    PropertyAnimation {
        id: animation3
        target: g1
        properties: "color"
        to: "gray"
        duration: 500
    }

    transform: Rotation {
        id: rotation
        origin.x: 30
        origin.y: 30
        axis {
            x: 1
            y: 0
            z: 0
        }
        angle: 0
    }

    gradient: Gradient {
        GradientStop { id: g1; position: 0.0; color: "blue" }
        GradientStop { id: g2; position: 1.0; color: "blue" }
    }

    states: State{
        name: "moved"; when: mouseArea.entered
        PropertyChanges { target: aaa; width: width+10; height: height+10 }
    }

    transitions: Transition {
        NumberAnimation { properties: "width,height"; duration: 1000 }
    }
}
```

I've tried both this version, and simplified one with only x, y, width, height and color properties, none worked.

Comment: Solved. My object name was overridden by a core object.

Comment: Can you please answer your own question and accept it when possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. I've been trying to override core object.